# Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, native, ads

I am implementing facebook native ads in unity that needs `gradle` build from unity. After importing to `Android Studio` and `gradle` sync it runs well but during signed APK it produces the error which is.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/unity3d/ads/android/BuildConfig.class

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more information related to your problem and be specific.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you have duplicate class definition for:

```
com.unity3d.ads.android.BuildConfig
```

Try look into your jar/aar to see if the class is present at multiple places.

I like to use grep (linux/osx) or 7-Zip to quickly explores my jar/aar files